# Youtube's video in full screen mode doesn't stretch beyond container's limits

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, fullscreen

It's strange since I embedded youtube clips many times in the past and it never happened. It happens only in Chrome, it works alright on Firefox and Edge.
The image below is a screenshot from full-screen mode in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: @Tiffany you are right, but while trying to filter the relevant code it turned out that this behaviour is caused by animation-fill-mode: both; in the css of one of the videos' parents. Thanks a lot!